# Show and hide fragment within an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently creating functionality to change `Fragments` using bottom navigation. But instead of destroying them and recreating them, I want to simply hide and show the fragments to preserve the member variables.

I've tried `replace()`, `hide()` and `show()` but haven't managed the get it right, I'm getting animation errors which I'm not able to track down.

I also can't find an example of switching fragments within an `AppCompatActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PassengerFragment passengerFragment;
    DriverFragment driverFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new PassengerFragment()).commit();
    }

    // this handles the bottom navigation so when you click an item it changes fragment
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_passenger:
                            selectedFragment = passengerFragment;
                            break;

                        case R.id.nav_driver:
                            if (driverFragment==null) {
                                selectedFragment = new DriverFragment();
                            }
                            else {
                                selectedFragment = driverFragment;
                            }

                            break;
                    }

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit(); <---- line 54

                    return true;
                }
            };
}
```

ERROR

> Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:396)
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:444)
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:434)
>           at je.digital.kevin_pickmeup.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:54)

Comment: Does app crash? If does, show Logcat output

Comment: Where does the variable `passengerFragment` assigned?

Comment: On click of which navigation menu does the app crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just needed better if statements to handle all the cases.

```
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                Fragment passengerFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("A");
                Fragment driverFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("B");

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_passenger:
                        if(passengerFragment.isHidden()) {
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(passengerFragment).commit();
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(driverFragment).commit();
                        }
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_driver:
                        if(driverFragment==null) {
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new DriverFragment(),"B").commit();
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(passengerFragment).commit();
                        }
                        else {
                            if(driverFragment.isHidden()) {
                                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(driverFragment).commit();
                                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(passengerFragment).commit();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying do replace with `Fragment` which are `null`. You have created `passengerFragment` and `driverFragment` as fields or global variables and than you are trying to use them but in some cases especially `passengerFragment` is `null`. If you are trying to keep the data in `Fragments` even they are replaced you can use `addToBackStack` but you will need to manage not to putting too much to back stack probably by checking `getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` and removing if there are more than 1 using `popBackStack()` or save the data in `Bundle` on `onDestroyView` and restore that data in `onCreateView`:

Comment: addToBackStack() doesn't hide the fragment though. That's what confuses me. How to hide one fragment and show the other.